# Reactor-netty http status from publisher

Tags: reactor-netty

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this,
The http response status depends on a body that I need to read.
So I have something like that:

```
private NettyOutbound handleRequest(HttpServerRequest req, HttpServerResponse res) {
    Mono<String> body = req.receive().aggregate().asString(UTF_8);
    ...
    return res.status(status)
                .sendString(body, UTF_8);
}

private int status(String body) {
    ...
}
```

But to get the status I need read the body, I don't see any option to use a value from publisher there. How can I make it so I can call `status` method above and use that status when creating `NettyOutbound`

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you are trying to implement route handler

I think the following should work

```
package hello;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.netty.DisposableServer;
import reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer;
import reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerRequest;
import reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse;

public class Application {
    
    private Mono<Void> handleRequest(HttpServerRequest req, HttpServerResponse res) {
        return req.receive().aggregate().asString().flatMap(body ->
                {
                    int status = status(body);
                    return res.status(status).sendString(Mono.just(body)).then();
                }
        );
    }

    private int status(String body) {
        return body.toLowerCase().equals("hello") ? 200 : 400;
    }

    public void startServer() {
        DisposableServer server =
                HttpServer.create()
                        .host("localhost")
                        .port(8080)
                        .route(routes -> routes.get("/hello", this::handleRequest))
                        .bindNow();
        
        server.onDispose().block();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().startServer();
    }
}
```